# Sitecore check if index is complete

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore

Is there a way in Sitecore in code that you can check if the lucene index exists or is complete?

We are in the making of a mechanism that will check if the index exists or is complete. If not it needs to be rebuild.

Edit: We use Sitecore version 7.2

Comment: Which Sitecore version? What do you mean by "is complete"? Does it mean that it was never rebuild yet?

Comment: We use sitecore version 7.2. By complete I mean is there a way that we can know if all the items (that need to be indexed) are in the index (we have had a problem lately where the index was incomplete and caused problems)

Comment: I always look in the Crawling log for activities to do with index rebuilding - it will tell you if an index rebuild fails or whether rebuild is in progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you have strategies like `OnPublishEndAsync`, `IntervalAsynchronous` etc. to keep your index up to date and they should be taking care of the completeness of it.

In the real world during rollouts, longer downtimes, network issues etc. the index can become inconsistent with the Sitecore tree or the rest of the indexes in your farm. In order to find out if the index(es) is(are) complete, you'd have to compare the Sitecore tree to the content of every single index in your web farm. That would require scanning through the tree, querying the index and doing a both-way comparison.

Given the difficulty of that task I would consider a combination of the Manual Strategy and the `RemoteRebuildStrategy` and do a nightly rebuild (if the availability requirements allow this).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to determine if the index has finished and therefore indexed all appropriate items is to check the index's Job and get its status. There is an official module on the Sitecore Marketplace that contains an aspx for you to view jobs that are currently running.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Support_Toolbox.aspx?sc_lang=en

If you access Jobs.aspx in the Module you can see the code to retrieve jobs and therefore select the one relating to your index to get its status. This is your best option to determine in code if all items have been indexed and the indexing has finished. I've included a snippet below for you.

```
var jobs = JobManager.GetJobs();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var type = typeof(Sitecore.Jobs.JobManager);
ShowJobs(sb, "Running jobs", ((SafeDictionary<Handle, Job>)type.GetField("_runningJobs", bindingFlags).GetValue(null)).Values.ToArray());
```

```
private void ShowJobs(StringBuilder sb, string name, Job[] enumerable)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(name);
        if (enumerable.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var job in enumerable)
            {
                long total = job.Status.Total;
                var span = now - job.QueueTime;
                sb.AppendLine(GetColor(job.Handle.ToString()) + job.QueueTime.ToLongTimeString() + If(() => span.Hours.ToString() == "0", () => string.Empty, () => span.Hours.ToString() + "h ") + If(() => span.Minutes == 0, () => string.Empty, () => span.Minutes.ToString() + "m ") + span.Seconds + "s ago)" + job.Name + job.Status.Processed + (total > 0 ? " of " + total : string.Empty) + job.Options.Priority);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendLine("No jobs");
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the answer to the question?